# is this a bug in Date.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, date

i [am using date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) to parse date in my javascript code

i just found an issue where i pass in

"12 Aug 2011" into a Date.Parse() method and it returns August 1, 2011.

here is a screenshot of the input string (as you can see i am passing in "12 Aug 2011"):
[image]

and here is a screenshot of the output date after the parse (as you can see it thinks its Aug 1 2011):
[image]

Is there anything i am doing wrong here or is this a bug in the library

Answer (score -1, accepted):

looks like i have to use parseExact()

```
 Date.parseExact(startingMilestone, "d MMM yyyy");
```

Comment: Shouldn't have to. I did exactly what you did and got the correct result http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/J3dnu/1/

Comment: @Mark - could it be something else? Environment related? version of date.js (i am using: Version: 1.0 Alpha-1 )?  again, my screenshot shows everything . . i checked the string and its simply "12 Aug 2011".  As mentioned, i have a solution (using parseExact) but this is still weird)

Comment: @ooo - As Mark said, this obviously isn't a bug in date.js because he has shown a working example. The code you haven't written must be wrong.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko - i can't argue with what you are saying but i am showing the input and output to a one line function in Date.js so there is still no explanation.

Comment: @ooo: you've included the wrong version of `date.js` perhaps?

Comment: @Mark - it looks like there is only one version on the website from back in 2007 - as i mentioned in the comment above: it says: Version: 1.0 Alpha-1

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that there is an error with date.js and its handling of August dates (in the format of Aug). However, the error is specific to the packaged version of the JS. If you use, the JS located at http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js, the error is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not a bug in `date.js`. Go to the page you linked us to an enter `12 Aug 2011`. It parses it just fine. There's a bug in your code somewhere.

Here's a fiddle as proof:

http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/J3dnu/

Comment: but i am showing you the input and output of that function ?? . . its possible the main page of date.js is not just using Date.Parse()

Comment: this seems to work: Date.parseExact(startingMilestone, "d MMM yyyy");

Comment: @ooo: Ok. See fiddle. I'm guessing `startingMilestone` is not what you think it is, or contains some weird characters..or.... I don't know.

Comment: if that was the case wouldn't parseExact break as well ?